# Asp.net MVC Drop-Down List with Html Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, dropdown

I'm Completely confused with lots of articles and tutorials about using html helper to generate drop-down list.
my goal is to have 2 drop-down in the first one I need a list of countries, then after choosing a country next drop-down shows tours available for that country.
but I'm stuck in the first drop down.

I create a model like this

```
public class test
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }   
}
```

and in my Controller I have this

```
   {
        var country = db.Countries.ToList();
        var vn = new test { Countries = country.ToList() };
        return View(vn);
    }
```

and in view `foreach` loop works correctly and it shows list of countries but my dropdown list has Error and I'm really confused how to fix it.

```
@model vidiaweb_com.Models.test
<div class="container" id="ttitle">

<nav class="">
    <ul class="resetpadmar">
        @foreach (var t in Model.Countries)
        {
            <li class="">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">

                   @t.CountryName

                </div>


            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, "Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

appreciate any help

Comment: What do you mean by *dropdown list has Error* ? Please, specify

Comment: Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much. I'm a little bit confused about the fiddle  but trying to understand . it seems that its exactly what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not see loaded data, it is because you does not supply any. You should alter your drop down list as below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", 
    Model.Countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.Id.ToString(),
        Text = m.Name
    }), 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Or even better, use strongly type version `DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, 
    Model.Countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.Id.ToString(),
        Text = m.Name
    }), 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Note:** `Text = m.Name` should be changed to match your model.

Comment: thanks i will work on it. is it possible to tell me what is value and why is it string?

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh, It is properties of `SelectListItem`. You can look at generated `<select>` html and see that `value` is `Value` of `<option>` and `Text` is displayed data. `Value` of selected option must be bound to your `Id`. It is string to support all types of data.

Comment: really thank you by your kind help. Appreciate.

Comment: you are welcome. But you will also need @HadiHassan 's answer to load tours related to country.

Comment: ofcourse but I need to improve my codes step by step. at first it was hard for me to understand his codes now I think its the time to work more on it. thanks both @Hadi Hassan and you also .

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called cascading dropdownlist in mvc

Your code should be done on the client side using `JQuery`, something like this

```
 $(function() {
   $('#CountryId').change(function() {
     var countrySelected = $('#CountryId:selected').val();
     countrySelected = countrySelected == "" ? 0 : countrySelected;
     //When select 'optionLabel' we need to reset it to default as well. So not need 
     //travel back to server.
     if (countrySelected == "") {
       $('#TourId').empty();
       $('#TourId').append('<option value="">--Select a Tour--</option>');
       return;
     }
     // call the method on the server to get all related trips
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '@Url.Action("YourActionName","ControllerName")',
       data: {
         'countryId': countrySelected
       },
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result) {
         var tourControl = $('#TourId');
         if (result != null) {

           tourControl.empty();
           $.each(result.tours, function(index, data) {
             // Here assuming that the value of tour is "Id" and display name is "Name"
             tourControl.append('<option value="' + data.Id + '">' + data.Name + '</option>');
           });
         }
       }
     });

   });
 });
```

and in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName(int countryId)
{
     var details = db.Tours.Where(t=>t.CountryId ==countryId);
     return Json(new {tours = details});
}
```

[here](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-cascading-example/) a full explanation with downloadable sample

Hope this will help you

Comment: really thank you.I will work on it then I will let you know thanks again

Comment: kindly accept my answer and upvote, if you found it helpful

Comment: sure if it helps thanks